# Grab "Gray" images from Basler cameras

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, image-formats

I am using Pylon software(Basler camera) in c#.NET. I grabbed frames from cameras with "bitmap" format, but i need images with "gray" format. How can i grab pylon images with "gray" format?
Thanks

Comment: What is *"gray"* format - I have heard of JPEG, PNG, TIFF but not *"gray"*. Why do you think you need *"gray"* format - who told you that, or which application requires it exactly?

Comment: in c,c++ or c# we can convert image format to another. for example below code convert RGB image to gray image.

var image = new Image<Bgr, Byte>(640, 360);
var gray = image.Convert<Gray, Byte>();

Comment: So... do that then. What's the problem?

Comment: Dear Mark, thank you for replying. In my project I'm using basler cameras and in these cameras the output images are "bitmap" but i need "gray" image, and i can not convert "bitmap" to "gray".

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:**

call this code in C# after you open camera and before you start grabbing:

```
camera.Parameters[PLCamera.PixelFormat].SetValue(PLCamera.PixelFormat.Mono8);
```

**Long answer:**

Images from cameras are always "Bitmap"

Basler cameras can provide you with different "[Pixel Format](https://docs.baslerweb.com/pixel-format)"
For example: you can setup camera "acA2040-120uc" to provide you with one from the following Pixel Format:

- Mono 8
- Bayer RG8
- Bayer RG12
- Bayer RG12 Packed
- RGB 8
- BGR 8
- YCbCr422_8

Pylon API provides you access to camera settings.
You can set "gray" format in C# using this code:

```
camera.Parameters[PLCamera.PixelFormat].SetValue(PLCamera.PixelFormat.Mono8);
```

(Mono8 means monochrome 8-bit)